# Is there are way to implement a method to upload files and view them from the server in MERN?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I want to implement a function to the user to upload files (just like docs, ppts, text files) and save to DB and another one to view that from getting from the server?
is there are any frameworks or npm modules for that?

Comment: you can upload files using for data and then use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for getting the files on the server side.you can then easily save the files to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
You can have one api endpoint to send files from your react app in the form of `FormData` and recieve/handle it in your express app using `Multer`. Then you can have another api endpoint to send file from your server and you can send the file using `res.sendFile()`.
In your react app you need to access the file convert it into `blob` and then into `dataUrl` and then you can view it easily using that `dataUrl`.